# Encrypt byte array, converting from string to 8bit integer array

Tags: c#, python, .net, encryption, type-conversion

I am trying to record audio raw data in python, ecrypt data and send it to .NET server where I decrypting received data and converting to byte array. When I converting received data to byte array like this Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(decryptedData) everything is almost working. But maximum byte value is 63 and maximum byte value of sending data is 255. Example of sent and received data:

Sent data

3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0, 252, 255, 1, 0, 255, 255, 1, 0, 0, 0...

Received data

3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 2, 0,  63,  63, 1, 0,  63,  63, 1, 0, 0, 0...

When I converting received data to byte array like this Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(DecryptData(aes, data)) everything is almost working. But high value is different. Example of sent and received data:

Sent data

6, 0, 8, 0, 250, 255, 255, 255, 3, 0, 6, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 3, 0, 6, 0, 3, 0...

Received data

6, 0, 8, 0, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 239, 191, 189, 3, 0, 6, 0, 2, 0, 4, 0, 3, 0, 6, 3, 0...

It seems like that converting generating more variables. I don't know.

Here is code of python of recording, encrypt and sending data:

```py
import pyaudio
import sys
import socket
import struct
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad

key = b"bpjAqrgO2N8q7Rfj8IHzeRxmP1W4HwUTWCRi7DQgyDc="
iv = b"Ta6e1cZAWQMM0QI66JC74w=="

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5005

chunk = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 2
RATE = 44100
RECORD_SECONDS = 5

pya = pyaudio.PyAudio()

stream = pya.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS, rate=RATE, input=True, output=True, frames_per_buffer=chunk)

print ("recording")
for i in range(0, 44100 // chunk * RECORD_SECONDS):
    data = stream.read(chunk)
    print (struct.unpack('{}B'.format(len(data)), data))
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    cipher_suite = AES.new(base64.urlsafe_b64decode(key), AES.MODE_CBC, base64.urlsafe_b64decode(iv))
    cipher_text = cipher_suite.encrypt(pad(data, 16))
    sock.sendto(cipher_text, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
    input ()
    # check for silence here by comparing the level with 0 (or some threshold) for 
    # the contents of data.
    # then write data or not to a file

print ("done")

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
pya.terminate()
```

Here is code of C# of receive, decrypt and convert data:

```cpp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DOTNETServer
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string IP = "127.0.0.1";
        private static int Port = 5005;
        private static string Key = "bpjAqrgO2N8q7Rfj8IHzeRxmP1W4HwUTWCRi7DQgyDc=";
        private static string IV = "Ta6e1cZAWQMM0QI66JC74w==";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UDPServer(IPAddress.Parse(IP), Port);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void UDPServer(IPAddress IP, int Port)
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[32768];
            IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IP, Port);
            UdpClient client = new UdpClient(endPoint);

            SymmetricAlgorithm aes = new AesManaged();
            aes.KeySize = 256;
            aes.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(Key);
            aes.IV = Convert.FromBase64String(IV);

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for data.");
                data = client.Receive(ref endPoint);
                var convertedReceivedData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DecryptData(aes, data));
                Console.Write("(");
                foreach(var item in convertedReceivedData)
                {
                    Console.Write(item + ", ");
                }
                Console.Write(")");
            }
        }

        static byte[] EncryptText(SymmetricAlgorithm aesAlgorithm, string text)
        {
            ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlgorithm.CreateEncryptor(aesAlgorithm.Key, aesAlgorithm.IV);
            byte[] data = new byte[32768];
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(cs))
                    {
                        writer.Write(text);
                    }
                }
                data = ms.ToArray();
            }

            return data;
        }

        static string DecryptData(SymmetricAlgorithm aes, byte[] data)
        {
            ICryptoTransform decryptor = aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
            byte[] encryptedDataBuffer = data;
            string plainText = "";
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(encryptedDataBuffer))
            {
                using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(cs))
                    {
                        plainText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }

            return plainText;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code in your server suggests that the decrypted data consist of text characters (why else would it use a StreamReader on the decrypted data stream, right?). But your Python code suggests (as far as i can tell) that the encrypted data are the "raw binary" bytes of the audio samples. So, unless i overlooked something or am otherwise mistaken, your server code does not match your client code on a conceptual level, as the server code seems to expect a different kind of encrypted data (text) than what the Python client delivers (non-text bytes).

Comment: Note that a text character is not synonymous with a byte and vice versa. Depending on the text encoding used, not all possible byte values can be translated to a character (such as with ASCII), or more than one byte (multiple bytes) will translate to only one character (such as with UTF-8). If you want to process byte data as byte data, why would you mess around with trying to interpret/process the byte data as text?

Comment: By the way, as a side note with regard to why you see the value 63 popping up there: 63 is the ASCII value of the character `?`, which is apparently being used as a substitute character by _Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes_ for any character in the "_plainText_" string that is not a valid ASCII character.

Comment: Yea I know about this but if I am not wrong, its not important. I though when I convert string back to byte array its same... Probably not... With normal message like text, string, after converting to byte array on client and then encrypt and sent and then received and decrpyt, message is fine. I though its all just about byte array converting. And CryptoStream doesn't suppport Write... I will try another way to decrypt probably...

Comment: Never, Never, Never take binary data an encode.  It will corrupt the data.  ASCII encoding with remove non printable characters which will make it impossible to recreate original data.  You can convert to 64 bit stream which is reversible and will gt original data.

Comment: The encryption/decryption is not the problem. The problem is that you seem to attempt to treat (binary) byte data as text and do some arbitrary pointless text operations/conversions on this data. No wonder that the original byte data is not preserved if you are doing that. The solution to your problem is simple: Treat and keep the decrypted byte data as byte data. Don't try treating it as something which it is not (don't try treating it like some form of text)

Comment: Thank you guys for advice. I will try change the code. It will by working with your advice I guess :)

Comment: One more side note: "_I though when I convert string back to byte array its same... Probably not..._" Well, this is not always guaranteed. But lets assume this could hypothetically work always: There is an even bigger blunder in your code that would prevent it from even hypothetically working. The default text encoding used by StreamReader is UTF-8. So the StreamReader tries to translate the bytes into a string/characters according to UTF-8 encoding. Then in your code you do `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes` in an attempt to get the bytes back. But ASCII is not the same as UTF-8. Kaboom!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I resolve my problem with the advice from elgonzo.
For sure I print the data byte per byte from data without any converting or unpacking in python like this:

```py
data = stream.read(chunk)
for item in data:
    print (item)
```

And in .NET application, just encrypt and decrypt with Rijndael what using input byte[] and have byte[] as output like this:

```cpp
public static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] cipherData, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    Rijndael alg = Rijndael.Create();

    alg.Key = Key;
    alg.IV = IV;

    CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, alg.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);            
    cs.Write(cipherData, 0, cipherData.Length);
    cs.Close();

    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

Thank you again and have a good day :)